# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 - Textures not showing on some devices

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

Riddle me this,

I recently published a game for Android (play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quackers if you want to witness the problems first hand), and initial feedback suggests that the thing doesn't run properly on some devices. I've since got ahold of one of the offending tablets (a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0) and it turns out it *does* run, it just wasn't rendering things properly.

A few digs later and I've discovered that it's a texturing issue. Textures are being loaded okay, but they're not being rendered - not the usual black squares you often get with OpenGL when something goes wrong - nothing at all.

This is OpenGL ES 2.0, doing an SDL/C++/ndk thing. While there are similar problems on the net, much of it involves ES 1.0 and regards a different issue - texture dimensions not being powers of two (e.g. 64x64, 128x128, 256x256 etc.) or some wacky compression stuff which doesn't apply here.

I've stripped out all of my rendering code and have gone back to basics - rendering a textured square (in a not particularly optimised manner).

Pre-loop code:

```
 SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
SDL_LogSetAllPriority(SDL_LOG_PRIORITY_VERBOSE);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_ES);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 2);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 0);

SDL_DisplayMode mode;
SDL_GetDisplayMode(0,0, &mode);
_currentWidth = mode.w;
_currentHeight = mode.h;

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

_screen = SDL_CreateWindow("window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, _currentWidth, _currentHeight, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(_screen);
SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(_screen, context); 

glViewport(0, 0, _currentWidth, _currentHeight);

//---
GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
const char *vs_source =     "attribute highp vec2 coord2d; "
                            "attribute highp vec2 texcoord;"
                            "varying highp vec2 f_texcoord;"
                            "void main(void) { "
                                "gl_Position = vec4(coord2d, 0.0, 1.0); "
                                "f_texcoord = texcoord;"
                            "}";
glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vs_source, NULL);
glCompileShader(vs);

GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
const char *fs_source =     "varying highp vec2 f_texcoord;"
                            "uniform sampler2D texture;"
                            "void main(void) { "
                                "vec2 flipped_texcoord = vec2(f_texcoord.x, 1.0 - f_texcoord.y);"
                                "gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, flipped_texcoord);"
                            "}";
glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fs_source, NULL);
glCompileShader(fs);

_program = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(_program, vs);
glAttachShader(_program, fs);
glLinkProgram(_program);

//---
GLuint vs2 = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
const char *vs_source2 =    "attribute vec2 coord2d; "
                            "void main(void) { "
                                "gl_Position = vec4(coord2d, 0.0, 1.0); "
                            "}";
glShaderSource(vs2, 1, &vs_source2, NULL);
glCompileShader(vs2);

GLuint fs2 = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
const char *fs_source2 =    "uniform lowp vec4 u_colour;"
                            "void main(void) { "
                                "gl_FragColor = u_colour;"
                            "}";
glShaderSource(fs2, 1, &fs_source2, NULL);
glCompileShader(fs2);

_flatProgram = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(_flatProgram, vs2);
glAttachShader(_flatProgram, fs2);
glLinkProgram(_flatProgram);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

//---------------------------------------

_screenRect.x = -1.0;
_screenRect.y = -1.0;
_screenRect.w = 2.0;
_screenRect.h = 2.0;

_superDuperFrameBuffer = 0;
_depthRenderBuffer = 0;

glGenTextures(1, &_screenTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _screenTexture);
if(_currentWidth < SCREENWIDTH*2 || _currentHeight < SCREENHEIGHT*2) {
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
}
else {
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
}

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_depthRenderBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthRenderBuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES, SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

// create a framebuffer object
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glGenFramebuffers(1, &_superDuperFrameBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _superDuperFrameBuffer);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _screenTexture, 0);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthRenderBuffer);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthRenderBuffer);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

_defaultFrameBuffer = 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &_defaultFrameBuffer);

glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

SDL_Surface* testSurface = IMG_Load("graphics/bg_01_0.png");

uint32_t rmask;
uint32_t gmask;
uint32_t bmask;
uint32_t amask;
#if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN
    rmask = 0xff000000;
    gmask = 0x00ff0000;
    bmask = 0x0000ff00;
    amask = 0x000000ff;
#else
    rmask = 0x000000ff;
    gmask = 0x0000ff00;
    bmask = 0x00ff0000;
    amask = 0xff000000;
#endif 

SDL_Surface *tempSurface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, testSurface->w, testSurface->h, 32, rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);

SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode(tempSurface, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
SDL_BlitSurface(testSurface, NULL, tempSurface, NULL);
testSurface = tempSurface;

SDL_FreeSurface(tempSurface);


GLint uniformTexture = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "texture");

_testTexture = 0;
glGenTextures(1, &_testTexture);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _testTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

//glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
//glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glUniform1i(uniformTexture, /*GL_TEXTURE*/0);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 256, 256, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, testSurface->pixels);

_vboTest = 0;
_vbo_cube_texcoords = 0;
glGenBuffers(1, &_vboTest);
glGenBuffers(1, &_vbo_cube_texcoords);
```

loop:

```
...

_quadColour[0] = 0.0f;
_quadColour[1] = 255.0f;
_quadColour[2] = 0.0f;
_quadColour[3] = 1.0f;
drawSquare(0, 0, 20, 20);


glViewport(0, 0, SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT);


GLfloat x1 = 0, x2 = 8, y1 = 0, y2 = 8;

glUseProgram(_program);

GLint attributeCoord2d = glGetAttribLocation(_program, "coord2d");
GLint attributeTexcoord = glGetAttribLocation(_program, "texcoord");


glEnableVertexAttribArray(attributeTexcoord);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _testTexture);

GLfloat cube_texcoords[] = {
    0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
};
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo_cube_texcoords);
glVertexAttribPointer(attributeTexcoord, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cube_texcoords), cube_texcoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(attributeCoord2d);

GLfloat triangle_vertices[] = {
    x1, y2,
    x1, y1,
    x2, y1,
    x2, y2,
};
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboTest);
glVertexAttribPointer(attributeCoord2d, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangle_vertices), triangle_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);


SDL_GL_SwapWindow(_screen);

...
```

obviously there's some stuff I've only added for testing purposes, like converting textures to RGBA and whatever. It draws a little green square, then a textured square.

Code might be messy but the point is this - two different results:

Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 (bork)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/peJgl.png

Nexus 7 (correct)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRYBw.png

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have your tried on other devices and gotten similar results due to GPU architectures? (Don't know if this is due to immediate vs deferred rendering)

Comment: I'm not rich enough to afford a bazillion devices :P But it's worked on everything else so far. I believe there may be similar faults on older Kindle HDXes - Amazon just reports a "black screen". I've also been told it fails on the 2012 Nexus 7 (but not the 2013 one which I own). There's been successes on a couple of HTC devices so it's very much hit-and-miss.

Comment: Power of 2 textures are still required on Opengl ES 2.  Non-power of 2 textures may work on some devices.

Comment: @RichardCritten ES 2.0 supports NPOT textures, with some restrictions (no mipmapping, only `CLAMP_TO_EDGE` wrap mode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few errors and possible issues in this code:

- Your fragment shader should not compile if the GLSL compiler is strict about error checking. Since you do not specify a default precision, and there is no default precision for float/vector/matrix types, you need an explicit precision for all declarations. It is missing for this variable:

  ```
  vec2 flipped_texcoord = vec2(f_texcoord.x, 1.0 - f_texcoord.y);
  ```

  If you want to stick with `highp`, this should be:

  ```
  highp vec2 flipped_texcoord = vec2(f_texcoord.x, 1.0 - f_texcoord.y);
  ```
- This call has a bad argument:

  ```
  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _screenTexture, 0);
  ```

  Since you're attaching a texture, the 3rd argument must be `GL_TEXTURE_2D` (you would need to use `glFramebufferRenderbuffer` for attaching a renderbuffer):

  ```
  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, screenTexture, 0);
  ```
- Make sure that the OES_packed_depth_stencil extension is supported on the device, since you're using it here:

  ```
  glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES, SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT);
  ```
- This code sequence does not make much sense:

  ```
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

  _defaultFrameBuffer = 0;
  glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &_defaultFrameBuffer);
  ```

  You just bound framebuffer 0, so the current framebuffer binding will always be 0 here. If you're concerned that the default framebuffer might not be 0, you have to query the value before the first time you change the binding.
- This is not a valid call in ES 2.0:

  ```
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  ```

  Enabling textures was only needed in fixed function OpenGL. Once you use shader, it will just use textures anytime the shader... uses textures. No need to explicitly enable anything.

Comment: Some of those are silly oversights or are a result of me poking the thing to see what would happen. However, that change to the fragment shader seems to have fixed something, so that's good news.

Comment: Yep, looks like the problem was a missing "highp". I long for the day when w're all using regular OpenGL and devices stop being so picky. Thanks a bunch, means I can get a patch out by the end of the week.

Answer (score 1):

Power-of-two textures are still required on many GLES 2.0 devices. From section 3.8.2 of the GLES 2.0 spec (https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf):

"Calling a sampler from a fragment shader will return (R; G;B;A) =
(0; 0; 0; 1) if any of the following conditions are true: ... A two-dimensional sampler is called, the corresponding texture image is a non-power-of-two image (as described in the Mipmapping discussion of section 3.7.7), and either the texture wrap mode is not CLAMP_TO_EDGE, or the minification filter is neither NEAREST nor LINEAR."

Assuming SCREENHEIGHT/SCREENWIDTH are the dimensions of your device, you're violating this restriction. You can ignore this restriction if your device supports some NPOT extension, for instance GL_OES_texture_npot (https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_npot.txt), although in my experience, some devices that report this extension still sample textures as black when the npot texture is the color target of a framebuffer. The best course is to just always use POT render targets in ES 2.0.

Comment: In the posted code, the wrap mode **is** `CLAMP_TO_EDGE`, and the minification filter **is** `LINEAR`. So none of the restrictions are violated.

Comment: I ran into this issue on a Galaxy Tab 2 P5110 (Android version 4.2.2).   I had mis-edited a PNG so it had a width of 226 instead of 256 used as a texture.   The Galaxy II phone and Nexus 4 both used the bitmap without issues, and the Tab 2 P5110 rendered nothing.   A call to glGetError returned zero.  I checked the bitmap as kicked out by decodeResource and it reported no alpha, premultipled false, and config ARGB_8888;